# xmlstarlet select iteratively multiple occurences of same tag

Tags: xml, shell, xmlstarlet

I am trying to select attribute values within multiple occurrences of same tag using xmlstarlet within a for loop ,but the $i in the iteration is not taking value as expected , I am referencing it as "$i" with escape characters within the -m ' ' , but it does not seem to be interpreting it correctly , not sure how I should approach this problem :

```
for i in {1..16};
do
FTRSERVER=`xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//JOB[\"$i\"]' -v './AUTOEDIT2[@NAME="%%FTP-RHOST"]/@VALUE' ~testhwa/FTPJobstable007.xml`
done
```

Text sample :

```
<JOB
     ACTIVE_TILL="20141124" 
     APPLICATION="CTDS0320" 
     APPL_FORM="AFT" 
     APPL_TYPE="FILE_TRANS" 
     APPL_VER="6.1.01" 
     APR="1" 
     AUG="1" 
     AUTHOR="wyy" 
     AUTOARCH="0" 
     CHANGE_DATE="20190403" 
     CHANGE_TIME="141554" 
     CHANGE_USERID="ecsadmin" 
     CM_VER="610" 
     CONFIRM="0" 
     CREATION_DATE="20190328" 
     CREATION_TIME="105555" 
     CREATION_USER="singhm7" 
     CRITICAL="0" 
     CYCLIC="0" 
     CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0" 
     CYCLIC_TYPE="Interval" 
     DAYS_AND_OR="OR" 
     DEC="1" 
     DESCRIPTION="Processes Source data files FTP from Source System" 
     DOCLIB="/prod/appl/ctds/Doc" 
     DOCMEM="energent_billing_delta.doc" 
     FEB="1" 
     GROUP="@CTDS-BW" 
     IND_CYCLIC="START" 
     INTERVAL="00000M" 
     JAN="1" 
     JOBNAME="energent_billing_delta-FTP" 
     JUL="1" 
     JUN="1" 
     MAR="1" 
     MAXDAYS="0" 
     MAXRERUN="0" 
     MAXRUNS="0" 
     MAXWAIT="7" 
     MAY="1" 
     MEMLIB="Not in use for application jobs" 
     MEMNAME="energent_billing_delta-FTP" 
     MULTY_AGENT="N" 
     NODEID="vprv0320" 
     NOV="1" 
     OCT="1" 
     OWNER="ctds_energent" 
     PARENT_TABLE="@CTDS" 
     PRIORITY="AA" 
     RETRO="0" 
     RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="OR" 
     SEP="1" 
     SHIFT="IGNOREJOB" 
     SHIFTNUM="+00" 
     SYSDB="0" 
     TASKTYPE="Job" 
     USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N" 
     WEEKSCAL="BCD-Y">
      <INCOND AND_OR="AND" NAME="CTDS0320-ENERGENT-BILLING-DELTA-OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
      <OUTCOND NAME="CTDS0320-ENERGENT-BILLING-DELTA-FTP" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="ADD"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ACCOUNT" VALUE="ctds_energent"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LOSTYPE" VALUE="Unix"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LUSER" VALUE="ctds"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ROSTYPE" VALUE="Windows"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RUSER" VALUE="controlm@enbridge.com"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LPATH1" VALUE="/prod/appl/ctds/Publish/ENERGENT/*"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPATH1" VALUE="/\Business Intelligence-Gas Consumption\Energent\Outgoing\Gas Consumption\"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-PATH" VALUE="Not in use for application jobs"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-USE_DEF_NUMRETRIES" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPF" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CLEAR_ALL" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CONNTYPE2" VALUE="FTP"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CONNTYPE1" VALUE="LOCAL"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LHOST" VALUE="Local"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RHOST" VALUE="hdq-nt164"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LPASSIVE" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPASSIVE" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD2" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD3" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD4" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD5" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRANSFER_NUM" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE1" VALUE="A"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE2" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE3" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE4" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE5" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UNIQUE1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM2" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM3" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM4" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM5" VALUE="1"/>
    </JOB>
    <JOB
    ACTIVE_TILL="20141124" 
     APPLICATION="CTDS-VPRV0342" 
     APPL_FORM="AFT" 
     APPL_TYPE="FILE_TRANS" 
     APPL_VER="6.1.01" 
     APR="1" 
     AUG="1" 
     AUTHOR="wyy" 
     AUTOARCH="0" 
     CHANGE_DATE="20190716" 
     CHANGE_TIME="233201" 
     CHANGE_USERID="pahwar" 
     CM_VER="610" 
     CONFIRM="0" 
     CREATION_DATE="20190611" 
     CREATION_TIME="072632" 
     CREATION_USER="pahwar" 
     CRITICAL="0" 
     CYCLIC="0" 
     CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0" 
     CYCLIC_TYPE="Interval" 
     DAYS_AND_OR="OR" 
     DEC="1" 
     DESCRIPTION="Processes Source data files FTP from Source System" 
     DOCLIB="/prod/appl/ctds/Doc/" 
     DOCMEM="energent_billing_delta.doc" 
     FEB="1" 
     GROUP="@CTDS-BW" 
     IND_CYCLIC="START" 
     INTERVAL="00000M" 
     JAN="1" 
     JOBNAME="energent_billing_delta-FTP" 
     JUL="1" 
     JUN="1" 
     MAR="1" 
     MAXDAYS="0" 
     MAXRERUN="0" 
     MAXRUNS="0" 
     MAXWAIT="7" 
     MAY="1" 
     MEMLIB="Not in use for application jobs" 
     MEMNAME="energent_billing_delta-FTP" 
     MULTY_AGENT="N" 
     NODEID="vprv0342" 
     NOV="1" 
     OCT="1" 
     OWNER="ctds_energent" 
     PARENT_TABLE="@CTDS-VPRV0342" 
     PRIORITY="AA" 
     RETRO="0" 
     RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="OR" 
     SEP="1" 
     SHIFT="IGNOREJOB" 
     SHIFTNUM="+00" 
     SYSDB="0" 
     TASKTYPE="Job" 
     USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N" 
     WEEKSCAL="BCD-Y">
      <INCOND AND_OR="AND" NAME="V0342-ENERGENT-BILLING-DELTA-OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
      <OUTCOND NAME="V0342-ENERGENT-BILLING-DELTA-FTP" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="ADD"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ACCOUNT" VALUE="ctds_energent"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LOSTYPE" VALUE="Unix"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LUSER" VALUE="ctds"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ROSTYPE" VALUE="Windows"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RUSER" VALUE="controlm@enbridge.com"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LPATH1" VALUE="/prod/appl/ctds/Publish/ENERGENT/*"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPATH1" VALUE="/\Business Intelligence-Gas Consumption\Energent\Outgoing\Gas Consumption\"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-PATH" VALUE="Not in use for application jobs"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-USE_DEF_NUMRETRIES" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPF" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CLEAR_ALL" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CONNTYPE2" VALUE="FTP"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CONNTYPE1" VALUE="LOCAL"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LHOST" VALUE="Local"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RHOST" VALUE="hdq-nt164"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LPASSIVE" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPASSIVE" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD2" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD3" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD4" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD5" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRANSFER_NUM" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE1" VALUE="A"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE2" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE3" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE4" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE5" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UNIQUE1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM2" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM3" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM4" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM5" VALUE="1"/>
    </JOB>
    <JOB
```

Regards,
Sriram.V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't work because `$i` inside a single-quoted string isn't evaluated by the shell.

If you replace `'//JOB[\"$i\"]'` with `'//JOB['"$i"']'` it'll do what you ask.

Rather than invoking `xmlstarlet` 16 times why not list matches in the first 16 JOB elements one per line (`-n` for newline):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//JOB[16 >= position()]/AUTOEDIT2[@NAME="%%FTP-RHOST"]' -v '@VALUE' -n data.xml
```

Output:

```
hdq-nt164
hdq-nt164
```

Comment: Great!!!Thanks a ton! , the reason for not having the extraction of Job Elements in one go is that I building another XML from this XML and this is just a small portion of a large Script.        Regards, Sriram.V